# python remove character regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to remove somme charaters by using regex with python 3.X :

I would like:

1-delete everything before  `"{"Extracts:..."`
For example :

```
"<body><p>{"Extracts":..." after "{"Extracts:..."
```

2-delete everything after `"...PageCount":1}` or `"...PageCount":3}` or `"...PageCount":45}`
For example

```
"...PageCount":1}</p></sup> after "...PageCount":1}"
"...PageCount":47}</p></sup> after "...PageCount":47}"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] to add some example input and output, and any code you've already tried.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I do not know what the result should be, for me it looks the same afterwards.

Comment: before "...PageCount":1}</p></sup> after "...PageCount":1}"
befor "...PageCount":47}</p></sup> after "...PageCount":47}"

Comment: Sorry the question was clarified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lookahead and lookbehind for this.

1) This will be match all character before `.*{"Extracts"`

```
r'.*(?={\"Extracts\":)'
```

2) This will be match all character after `"PageCount":x}`

```
r'(?<=\"PageCount\":[0-9]+\}).*'
```

https://regex101.com/r/fu2hDJ/1
https://regex101.com/r/wccBs1/1

OR

You can use this regex for match your dictionnary:

```
{"Extracts":.*"PageCount":[0-9]+}
```

Comment: thanks for the seconde : b= """ ..PageCount":47}</p></sup> """""
json= re.sub(r'(?<=\"PageCount\":[0-9]+\}).*','',b )  I have this error on jupyter : error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Comment: arf, you can't use + or * in lookbehind... so, try to use r'{"Extracts":.*"PageCount":[0-9]+}' for select what you want instead of deleting what you do not want.

Comment: this select what I don't want ^^

Comment: "<body><p>{"Extracts":..."  and "...PageCount":1}</p></sup> => <body><p></p></sup> it give me this

Comment: got it thanks : json= re.findall( r'{"Extracts":.*"PageCount":[0-9]+}',str(json ) )!!